# Возникает ошибка C2039 там где не должна

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры-данных

есть 2 структуры данных, одна нужна для упрощения второй

```
struct vershina
{
    vershina* LinkStraight; // указатель на следующий элемент массива (пока не использ.)
    connect svyazi[50]; // массив указателей - связей 
    int id;
    string name;
    unsigned int valid_connects = 0;//сколько инициализированно связей
};
//структура связи, хранит указатель на связанный элемент и вывод при переходе
struct connect
{
    string out; //что выходит
    vershina* connect; // с чем соединено
};
```

При попытке обратиться к ним в main вот так возникает ошибка С2039

```
int valid_connects;
    int findIndex;
vershina *toPTR;
vershina list[100];
string transout;
.
.
.
list[findIndex].svyazi[valid_connects].connect = toPTR;
        list[findIndex].svyazi[valid_connects].out = transout;
```

svyazi: не является членом "vershina"

Не понимаю где ошибся, т.к. вроде обращаюсь сначала к элементу массива, затем к полю данных этого элемента, которое тоже массив, к номеру в нем и к полю данных элемента 2 массива. Структура запутанная, но не противоречивая.

Comment: Интересно, по какой логике половина имен понятны на русском, а  другие на английском?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На момент определения `struct vershina`, идентификатор `connect` ещё не определён. Чтобы решить Вашу проблему необходимо перенести определение `struct connect` перед `struct vershina`. Но и этого будет недостаточно, потому что в `struct connect` используется тип `vershina`. Поэтому перед `struct connect` необходимо сделать предварительное объявление типа `vershina`. Делается это так:

```
struct vershina;
```

Всё вместе будет выглядеть так:

```
struct vershina;

struct connect
{
    string out;
    vershina* connect;
};

struct vershina
{
    vershina* LinkStraight;
    connect svyazi[50];
    int id;
    string name;
    unsigned int valid_connects = 0;
};
```